# I am trying to push a list to the console but its not working and keeps pushing the code around the list with it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to push a list of products and their prices to console but every time I try it pushes the text to the console but it turns out like this --> `<ol><li>Small Hawaiian Pizza $8</li></ol>   Total comes to $8`

I'm still learning to code and I don't have any real experience with arrays. So I am reaching out to anyone willing to help :)

This is just a small piece of the code below

```
    let pizzaSize1 = [],pizzas = [], response, ppLen, i, text= [];
    let numbers = [];// declaration of variables
    let arrSum;


      if (pizzaSize1 === "{Hawaiian:Small}") {
            response = "The Pizza Costs " + "$8";
            let price = 8;
            numbers.push(price);
            let pname = "Small Hawaiian Pizza";
            pizzas.push(pname + " " + "$" + price)

        }

        if (pizzaSize1 === "{Hawaiian:Medium}") {
            response = "The Pizza Costs " + "$10";
            let price = 10;
            numbers.push(price);
            let pname = "Medium Hawaiian Pizza";
            pizzas.push(pname + " " + "$" + price)
        }

        if (pizzaSize1 === "{Hawaiian:Large}") {
            let price = 10;
            numbers.push(price);
            let pname = "Large Hawaiian Pizza";
            pizzas.push(pname + " " + "$" + price)
        }

        arrSum = numbers.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
        console.log(arrSum);

        ppLen = pizzas.length;
        text = "<ol>";
        for (i = 0; i < ppLen; i++) {
            text += "<li>" + pizzas[i] + "</li>";
        }
        text += "</ol>" + "   Total comes to" + " $" + arrSum;
        console.log(text);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're expecting instead? Your last 5  or so lines are `text = "<ol>"; text += "<li>" + ... + "</li>"; text += "</ol>" + "   Total comes to" + " $" + arrSum;` **EDIT:** Perhaps you're looking to actually see it as a list? What you're outputting is an HTML string, but console does not render HTML markup; it outputs the values of items exactly as-is. If you want to see it as a list, add it an element on the page, and it will be read/rendered as HTML.

Comment: I output it to a paragraph in the HTML and it came out fine formatting wise, how can I get the list to just push to the console like: Small Hawaiian pizza $8    and have nothing around it?

Comment: Consider having another variable where you only add the pieces you're concerned with, and output *that* to console instead of your `text` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (i = 0; i < ppLen; i++) {
 {
  console.log( pizzas[i] );  
 }
```

just this?

Comment: Due to   let pname = "Small Hawaiian Pizza";
            pizzas.push(pname + " " + "$" + price);